# Ruby on rails "NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::REMEMBER_OPTIONS"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I am trying to learn web development with ruby on rails. I have been following a course on Lynda.com and my steps were as follows:

1. I installed Ruby + DevKit 2.4.4-1(x64)
2. I installed rails as in the command line as follows
   `gem install rails --version 5.0.0`
3. I installed MySQL version 5.7.21
4. I installed mysql2 gem as follows
   `gem install mysql2`
5. I installed Atom text editor
6. I created a new project `rails new kudaweb -d mysql`
7. I created the required databases in the MySQL shell

`CREATE DATABASE kudaweb_development;` and `CREATE DATABASE kudaweb_test;`

8. I then created a new user and granted all privileges as follows

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON kudaweb_development.* TO 'rails_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'` 
and i did this for the test database as well

9. I configured the database.yml file as follows:

   `default: &default
     adapter: mysql2
     encoding: utf8
     pool: 5
     username: rails_user
     password: mypassword
     host: localhost`
10. I ran the following code to check if I had correctly configured the database

`rails db:schema:dump`

and I got the following error

`C:\Users\Dj K-Staxx\Desktop\RUBY\kudaweb>rails db:schema:dump
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::REMEMBER_OPTIONS
bin/rails:4:in`require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump`

I have no idea how to resolve this. I have searched the internet for solutions but to no avail. I am using windows 7 64bit and for the mysql2 gem I am using version 0.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there may be some config issue between your `0.5.0` gem and mysql.  It may not have built correctly. see: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/954

## Option 1:  try reverting to `0.4.9` or `0.4.10` gem

set your gemfile to:

```
# ./Gemfile
...
gem 'mysql2', '0.4.9'
...
```

## Option 2:  try to compile the gem locally with c-connector

You may need a local C-connector to properly build the gem locally.  see: https://www.digitalgyan.org/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-mysql2-gem-on-windows-10/

that may be as simple as downloading the appropriate files from MySQL:  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

In either scenario, you may benefit from a quick script to test out connection (to rule out Rails as the problem).

```
require 'mysql2'
client = Mysql2::Client.new(host: "localhost", username: "rails_user", password: "mypassword")
```

Answer (score 0):

update mysql2 gem in the Gemfile as:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.2'
```